# Python 2.7, how to assign the "unicode literal representation" of a unicode instance to an str instance?

Tags: string, python-2.7, unicode

Let's assume a `unicode` instance:

```
uni = u"but\u014dden"
```

Now, we could call `string = uni.encode("utf-8")` to output an utf-8 encoded byte string representation of this object. But that is not what we want to achieve. Instead, we would like to assign the *unicode literal representation* of this variable to a byte string, so the following statement evaluates to true:

```
# string = do_the_thing(uni)
string == "u\"but\\u014dden\""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) to create a literal from a unicode object:

```
string = repr(uni)
```

This'll use `\uhhhh` escape sequences for *all* codepoints over U+00FF; it'll use `\xhh` escapes for anything non-printable in the ASCII and Latin-1 ranges, and the standard one-letter escapes (like `\n`) for *some* of the characters that have one defined. It'll also favour single quotes over double, unless the string value contains single quotes (and no double quotes).

Demo:

```
>>> uni = u"but\u014dden"
>>> repr(uni)
"u'but\\u014dden'"
>>> repr(u'Latin 1 and a newline: å\n')
"u'Latin 1 and a newline: \\xe5\\n'"
>>> repr(u'Quoting 1: \'')
'u"Quoting 1: \'"'
>>> repr(u'Quoting 2: \'\"')
'u\'Quoting 2: \\\'"\''
```

Comment: I had a feeling it had to be simple: thank you, take this upvote ; )